# Mentor/Mentee software options - online app

Tags: android, web, apple

I am in a company of 700+ employees with varying ages and career backgrounds. I have been asked to look into options using any one of the options mentioned in the subject to set up some sort of "be a mentor" or "be mentored". Ideally, it would be similar to a dating site, but with different questions obviously or for a different purpose.

The idea is to allow employees to fill in a series of questions about their career interests be it hard or soft skills related to the company's goals. This gives the opportunity for employees to reach out to fellow co-workers and build a network of interests. If one wants to be mentored they could fill in a series of questions and then search for people with similar interests or else provide recommendations.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of an off the shelf site that does this via any online platform?

Comment: At the moment you are looking at such a software - StackExchange has also on-premise systems. For other alternatives see here: [Are there any clones/alternatives for running a Stack Exchange style Q&A site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site)